# How do I make a program that determines the next general meeting day in the form of the day of a week?

Tags: c#

How do I make a program that determines the next general meeting day in the form of the day of a week (Sunday-0,Monday-1,Tuesday-2,Wednesday-3,etc.) after inputting a day of the week and then putting in a numerical number (such as 22) of how many more days until the next meeting to where the console prints out what day of the week is the meeting (which is the part I'm struggling on).

I've already tried making a string to try to print out the result, but it would print out the wrong result. Then I tried making an equation including the day of the week (and how many days left (22 days) to print out the result, but nothing would print even though I typed for it to print.

Here is the most recent code I've tried with the program:

```
using System;

namespace NextMeeting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int Day = 6;
            int meeting = 0;
            int DayofWeek = meeting % 7;

            if (Day < 1 && Day > -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Sunday");
            }

            if (Day < 2 && Day > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Monday");
            }

            if (Day < 3 && Day > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Tuesday");
            }

            if (Day < 4 && Day > 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Wednesday");
            }

            if (Day < 5 && Day > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Thursday");
            }

            if (Day < 6 && Day > 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Friday");
            }

            if (Day < 7 && Day > 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Today is Saturday");
            }

            if (DayofWeek < 0 && DayofWeek > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Meeting day is " + (Day+1));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The days left until the meeting is " + meeting);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem understanding your problem. Can you add to your question an example of the input and output expected? And why you get that output from the input values?

Comment: I agree with @Steve it is unclear for me.

Comment: int day = 6 means that the program prints "Today is Saturday" Int meeting=22 (Didn't mean to put 0) means the program prints "The days left until the meeting is 22" and I am having trouble trying to get the program to calculate and print the day of the week  that the next general meeting is (For example, "Meeting day is on a Monday"

Comment: Sunday not Monday, sorry I've been working on this program for days and am so frustrated and tired

Comment: Your conditions are overly complicated. You're dealing with `int` values so `Day < 1 && Day > -1` should be `Day == 0`, and so on, and `DayofWeek < 0 && DayofWeek > 1` will never be true.

Comment: You are handling this task with the wrong tools. A date should be treated with a DateTime variable. DateTime variables have methods to add days (or months, years, etc) to a start date. DateTime variables have a property called DayOfWeek that gives you the output expected

Comment: How do I do that? can you give me an example?

Comment: Try to get an input date from the console. Convert the input string to a DateTime with DateTime.TryParse, Then write out the DayOfWeek property, finally call the AddDays method and again write out the DayOfWeek property for the new calculated date

Comment: I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for the day of the week of a meeting, if you know how many days you have between now and the day of the meeting.

```
var day = DateTime.Now; // today
Console.WriteLine($"Today is {day.DayOfWeek}");

int meeting = 21; // meeting in 21 days

var meetingDay = day.AddDays(meeting);

Console.WriteLine($"The meeting is on {meetingDay.DayOfWeek}");
Console.Read();
```

If you run it today (September 24, 2019) the response will be:

```
Today is Tuesday
The meeting is on Tuesday
```